# How can I distinguish a tablet from an older laptop or desktop with media queries?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries, tablet

There're apparently a lot of common breakpoints with media query screen sizes to detect/develop for mobile devices and tablets, as well as ways of detecting retina displays using pixel ratio media queries, but how can I go about telling the difference between an older ipad or another tablet that doesn't have retina display and a laptop or smaller desktop screen that has roughly the same resolution?

The interface I'm working with needs to change depending on whether the user has a mouse or a touchscreen, and things like an older ipad at horizontal orientation can easily be confused for an older laptop or desktop display.

So what's the best way of distinguishing between mobile tablets and older laptops or desktops that have similar resolutions?

Answer (score 1):

[WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) or [DeviceAtlas](https://deviceatlas.com/)

If you are strictly targeting iOS tablets, then there are specific media queries for them, in both orientations.

Just out of curiosity, what type of UI would require a different mouse or touchscreen view?  The only reason I can think of is a gaming solution?

Comment: A sort of slide-show interface that would require different size buttons and other UI elements based on whether or not the user has a mouse or a touch screen. I'm targeting any tablets possible, but I don't entirely know my audience, beyond the fact that they use tablets, and the more devices they're allowed to use, the better. The trouble is differentiating between tablets with a certain range of screen sizes and older laptops or desktops that are comparable, if not the same screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the modernizr library (http://modernizr.com/ ) to detect if its a touch device and work from there?

Modernizr allows you to have different CSS depending on whether touch inputs:

```
html.touch a {
   Padding:10px;
}

html.no-touch a {
   Padding:4px;
}
```

Comment: According to modernizr, their touch only indicates whether or not the browser can support it, which as I've gathered, doesn't necessarily mean they're using a tablet.

Comment: Yep by no means a fool proof solution but a good result with very little effort!